# How to convert between Lat Long and MGRS using javascript without dependence on libraries

Tags: javascript, mapping, type-conversion

I have a mapping app running in a browser than needs to be able to convert between latitude longitude and MGRS. I need to keep the load time of the app fast so I do not want to include any libraries with additional functions I do not need.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by developing the following two functions combining bits from two primary sources plus others on the internet. I have optimised them for speed not understanding!

My two primary sources were:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html
http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html

Example usage : MGRSString (51.172,-1.779) returns
"30U WB 85358 69660"

```
function MGRSString (Lat, Long)
{ 
if (Lat < -80) return 'Too far South' ; if (Lat > 84) return 'Too far North' ;
var c = 1 + Math.floor ((Long+180)/6);
var e = c*6 - 183 ;
var k = Lat*Math.PI/180;
var l = Long*Math.PI/180;
var m = e*Math.PI/180;
var n = Math.cos (k);
var o = 0.006739496819936062*Math.pow (n,2);
var p = 40680631590769/(6356752.314*Math.sqrt(1 + o));
var q = Math.tan (k);
var r = q*q;
var s = (r*r*r) - Math.pow (q,6);
var t = l - m;
var u = 1.0 - r + o;
var v = 5.0 - r + 9*o + 4.0*(o*o);
var w = 5.0 - 18.0*r + (r*r) + 14.0*o - 58.0*r*o;
var x = 61.0 - 58.0*r + (r*r) + 270.0*o - 330.0*r*o;
var y = 61.0 - 479.0*r + 179.0*(r*r) - (r*r*r);
var z = 1385.0 - 3111.0*r + 543.0*(r*r) - (r*r*r);
var aa = p*n*t + (p/6.0*Math.pow (n,3)*u*Math.pow (t,3)) + (p/120.0*Math.pow (n,5)*w*Math.pow (t,5)) + (p/5040.0*Math.pow (n,7)*y*Math.pow (t,7));
var ab = 6367449.14570093*(k - (0.00251882794504*Math.sin (2*k)) + (0.00000264354112*Math.sin (4*k)) - (0.00000000345262*Math.sin (6*k)) + (0.000000000004892*Math.sin (8*k))) + (q/2.0*p*Math.pow (n,2)*Math.pow (t,2)) + (q/24.0*p*Math.pow (n,4)*v*Math.pow (t,4)) + (q/720.0*p*Math.pow (n,6)*x*Math.pow (t,6)) + (q/40320.0*p*Math.pow (n,8)*z*Math.pow (t,8));
aa = aa*0.9996 + 500000.0;
ab = ab*0.9996; if (ab < 0.0) ab += 10000000.0;
var ad = 'CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX'.charAt (Math.floor (Lat/8 + 10));
var ae = Math.floor (aa/100000);
var af = ['ABCDEFGH','JKLMNPQR','STUVWXYZ'][(c-1)%3].charAt (ae-1);
var ag = Math.floor (ab/100000)%20;
var ah = ['ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUV','FGHJKLMNPQRSTUVABCDE'][(c-1)%2].charAt (ag);
function pad (val) {if (val < 10) {val = '0000' + val} else if (val < 100) {val = '000' + val} else if (val < 1000) {val = '00' + val} else if (val < 10000) {val = '0' + val};return val};
aa = Math.floor (aa%100000); aa = pad (aa);
ab = Math.floor (ab%100000); ab = pad (ab);
return c + ad + ' ' + af + ah + ' ' + aa + ' ' + ab;
};
```

To convert back from mgrs to lat long use the following function. The input string must have metre (i.e. 5 digit) easing and northing resolution and have spaces as output by the above function.

```
function LatLongFromMGRSstring (a) 
{
var b = a.trim();
b = b.match(/\S+/g);
if (b == null || b.length != 4) return [false,null,null];
var c = (b[0].length < 3) ? b[0][0] : b[0].slice(0,2);
var d = (b[0].length < 3) ? b[0][1] : b[0][2];
var e = (c*6-183)*Math.PI / 180;
var f = ["ABCDEFGH","JKLMNPQR","STUVWXYZ"][(c-1) % 3].indexOf(b[1][0]) + 1;
var g = "CDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXX".indexOf(d);
var h = ["ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUV","FGHJKLMNPQRSTUVABCDE"][(c-1) % 2].indexOf(b[1][1]);
var i = [1.1,2.0,2.8,3.7,4.6,5.5,6.4,7.3,8.2,9.1,0,0.8,1.7,2.6,3.5,4.4,5.3,6.2,7.0,7.9];
var j = [0,2,2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,0,0,0,2,2,4,4,6,6,6];
var k = i[g];
var l = Number(j[g]) + h / 10;
if (l < k) l += 2;
var m = f*100000.0 + Number(b[2]);
var n = l*1000000 + Number(b[3]);
m -= 500000.0;
if (d < 'N') n -= 10000000.0;
m /= 0.9996; n /= 0.9996;
var o = n / 6367449.14570093;
var p = o + (0.0025188266133249035*Math.sin(2.0*o)) + (0.0000037009491206268*Math.sin(4.0*o)) + (0.0000000074477705265*Math.sin(6.0*o)) + (0.0000000000170359940*Math.sin(8.0*o));
var q = Math.tan(p);
var r = q*q;
var s = r*r;
var t = Math.cos(p);
var u = 0.006739496819936062*Math.pow(t,2);
var v = 40680631590769 / (6356752.314*Math.sqrt(1 + u));
var w = v;
var x = 1.0 / (w*t); w *= v;
var y = q / (2.0*w); w *= v;
var z = 1.0 / (6.0*w*t); w *= v;
var aa = q / (24.0*w); w *= v;
var ab = 1.0 / (120.0*w*t); w *= v;
var ac = q / (720.0*w); w *= v;
var ad = 1.0 / (5040.0*w*t); w *= v;
var ae = q / (40320.0*w);
var af = -1.0-u;
var ag = -1.0-2*r-u;
var ah = 5.0 + 3.0*r + 6.0*u-6.0*r*u-3.0*(u*u)-9.0*r*(u*u);
var ai = 5.0 + 28.0*r + 24.0*s + 6.0*u + 8.0*r*u;
var aj = -61.0-90.0*r-45.0*s-107.0*u + 162.0*r*u;
var ak = -61.0-662.0*r-1320.0*s-720.0*(s*r);
var al = 1385.0 + 3633.0*r + 4095.0*s + 1575*(s*r);
var lat = p + y*af*(m*m) + aa*ah*Math.pow(m,4) + ac*aj*Math.pow(m,6) + ae*al*Math.pow(m,8);
var lng = e + x*m + z*ag*Math.pow(m,3) + ab*ai*Math.pow(m,5) + ad*ak*Math.pow(m,7);
lat = lat*180 / Math.PI;
lng = lng*180 / Math.PI;
return [true,lat,lng];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I searched for the official MGRS formula, but one of our sources is not available anymore. Nevertheless I tried to figure out what

```
var af = ['ABCDEFGH','JKLMNPQR','STUVWXYZ'][(c-1)%3].charAt (ae-1);
```

should do, I would like to port your code it to c++.

Comment: Each MGRS grid reference consists of a grid zone designator followed by a 100km square identifier followed by either 2,4,6,8 or 10 numerals, half of which are eastings and the other half northings, the more numerals the more accurate the reference.

Comment: Stepping back to the grid zones, each of these is a segment of the earth's surface, six degrees in longitude and eight degrees in latitude. The grid zone designator is a numeral between 0 and 59 (60*6=360!) denoting the longitude, followed by a letter denoting the latitude. The letters in the grid zones in one eight degree longitude block are chosen so as to be totally distinct from the letters in the grid zones in both of the eight degree longitude chunks on either side. So there are three sets of eight letters used and these repeat every 64 degrees of latitude (8*8=64).

Comment: So to answer your question, ['ABCDEFGH','JKLMNPQR','STUVWXYZ'] is an three element array containing the sets of letters used for the northings elem

Comment: ent of the grid zone designator. [(c-1)%3], where c is the easting element of the grid zone designator, picks which of these three character strings to use, the % being a modulus operator and finally charAt (ae-1) picks the correct letter to use for the northing element of the grid zone designator from the character string chosen earlier. Hope this helps.